# I have a nav in my web filter. the main menu works fine, but the sub menu ul li not appear. how to enable it

Tags: jquery, nav

I have a nav in my web filter. the main menu works fine, but the sub menu ul li not appear. how to enable it. Thank you.

```
<div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                        <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
                        <ul class="dl-menu">
                            <li><a href="#portfolio-filter" title="hosteleria" data-filter=".hosteleria">Hosteleria</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                    <li><a href="#portfolio-filter" title="bar" data-filter=".bar">bar</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#portfolio-filter" title="cafeteria" data-filter=".cafeteria">cafeteria</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#portfolio-filter" title="discoteca"  data-filter=".discoteca">discoteca</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#portfolio-filter" title="restaurante"  data-filter=".restaurante">restaurante</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#portfolio-filter" title="pub"data-filter=".pub">pub</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
</div>
```

have to connect with the elements of the portfolio

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var $container = $('#portfolio-container')
// initialize Isotope
    $container.isotope({
        // options...
        resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
        layoutMode : 'fitRows',
        itemSelector : '.element',
        animationEngine : 'best-available',

        // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
    });

    // update columnWidth on window resize
    $(window).smartresize(function(){
        $container.isotope({
        // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
        });
    });
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){

            $container.isotope({
        // options...
            });
    });

    $('#dl-menu a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: insert html code please

Comment: or make a little fiddle